# Is there any graphical front-end for darling?

Tags: virtualization, gui, mac

I want to run a mac app on Ubuntu 20.04. I don't want to install a virtual machine. I want to use Darling to run mac apps.
Wine has a graphical frontend called PlayOnlinux. It makes the process a lot easier to run a windows app. So, is there any graphical frontend for Darling?

Comment: Thank you @user535733 for your answer. I also saw that. But as I'm a noob, I didn't understand that that was the answer I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As of Mid-2020, Darling has no Graphical User Interface (GUI). Sorry.

Comment: Is a GUI in development?